# Get notified when expo audio player finishes playing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

i'm traying to get notigfication to display some messages, when expo Audio finishes playing, is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Example with onplaybackstatusupdate event: https://snack.expo.io/H1WiQG71M